# iRedMail: Domain alias not working with external mails

Tags: postfix-mta, diacritics, dovecot, iredmail

After successfully setting up an iRedMail server for my main domain, I tried to add my secondary domain as an alias by following the steps on here: https://docs.iredmail.org/sql.add.alias.domain.html

This didn't do the trick just yet, so I additionally added the secondary domain into the /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_domains = domain2.tld
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Note: I didn't remove any of the existing mysql entries under virtual_alias_maps.

And entered the mapping into /etc/postfix/virtual and executed "postmap /etc/postfix/virtual" afterwards:

```
@domain2.tld     @domain1.tld
```

This is working internally on the server. user1@domain1.tld can send to user2@domain2.tld and user2 will receive the mail in his mailbox. External emails also still arrive when sent to user@domain1.tld.

Unfortunately it doesn't function with external mails to the secondary domain.
In my /var/logs/mail.log I find the following lines:

```
postfix/smtpd[5541]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-oi1-x231.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::231]: 451 4.3.5 <user1@domain2.tld>: Recipient address rejected: Server configuration problem; from=<username@gmail.com> to=<user1@domain2.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-oi1-x231.google.com>
```

And:

```
postfix/smtpd[5644]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:12340: Connection timed out
```

On port 12340 dovecot is listening:

```
dovecot    513      root   67u  IPv4  17087      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:12340 (LISTEN)
```

In my dovecot log I find the following line repeatedly:

```
dovecot: quota-status: Error: quota-status: Client sent invalid recipient address: Invalid character in path
```

And that's where I'm stuck. I suspect one of two things:
Either I simply missed a necessary configuration, which seems highly likely, since I've never set up a mail server on Debian before, or the dovecot error is caused by my secondary domain. The secondary domain contains an umlaut (ä/ö/ü), which I'm well aware can cause some issues. Therefore I also own the domain in it's punycode formatted variant. So, whenever I added my secondary domain with it's umlaut to a configuration, I also added the punnycode version of it, assuming it would solve any issues in that regard.

Is it possible that dovecot can't handle any umlauts/punnycode formats? Or did I simply miss to configure something obvious?

Any push into the right direction is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Snot

==== Basic Info ====

- iRedMail version: 1.4.0 MARIADB edition
- Linux/BSD distribution name and version: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) - 10.10
- Used DB: MySQL (MariaDB)
- Web server: Nginx

==== Edit ====

After some further testing with different external mail hosters, I realized that 2 out of 4 mails arrived when sent to the domain with the umlaut. GMail and Hotmail didn't, my company exchange and some other web provider came through.

iRedMail/postfix/dovecot/whateverelseisinvolved seem to be working fine with punnycode/umlauts per se, it just seems to depend on the sender. Any guess as to why or what logs I could check to dig deeper into this?

==== Edit ====

As far as the base setup; After a clean Debian 10 installation I've followed the steps in this guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/debian-10-buster-iredmail-email-server

Any specific config that alters from the guide has been mentioned in the post. I've additionally issued a certificate which includes the main domain and the secondary domain in punnycode.

Here the various logs on boot:

/var/log/mail.log:

```
Aug 14 14:24:36 s postfix/postfix-script[1637]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Aug 14 14:24:37 s amavis[573]: starting. /usr/sbin/amavisd-new at host.domain1.tld amavisd-new-2.11.0 (20160426), Unicode aware, LC_ALL="C", LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
Aug 14 14:24:37 s postfix/postfix-script[1819]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug 14 14:24:37 s postfix/master[1821]: daemon started -- version 3.4.14, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: Net::Server: Group Not Defined.  Defaulting to EGID '121 121'
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: Net::Server: User Not Defined.  Defaulting to EUID '113'
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: No ext program for   .F, tried: unfreeze, freeze -d, melt, fcat
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: No ext program for   .zoo, tried: zoo, unzoo
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: No decoder for       .F   
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: No decoder for       .zoo 
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: Using primary internal av scanner code for clamav-socket
Aug 14 14:24:39 s amavis[1915]: Found secondary av scanner clamav-clamscan at /usr/bin/clamscan
```

/var/log/dovecot/dovecot.log:

```
Aug 14 14:24:26 s dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4) starting up for pop3, imap, sieve, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Aug 14 14:24:43 s dovecot: stats: Error: (stats-reader): didn't reply with a valid VERSION line: EXPORT#011global
Aug 14 14:24:43 s dovecot: stats: Error: (stats-reader): didn't reply with a valid VERSION line: EXPORT#011global
```

grep postfix /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 14 14:24:36 s postfix/postfix-script[1637]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Aug 14 14:24:37 s postfix/postfix-script[1819]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug 14 14:24:37 s postfix/master[1821]: daemon started -- version 3.4.14, configuration /etc/postfix
```

I've disabled thequota features and enabled SMTPUTF8 in my postfix main.cf, no notable change except from an additional line on boot in the mail.log:

```
Aug 14 14:59:46 s amavis[571]: starting. /usr/sbin/amavisd-new at host.domain1.tld amavisd-new-2.11.0 (20160426), Unicode aware, LC_ALL="C", LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

The behaviour is still the same unfortunately. After further analyzing the logs I realized that it seems as if the mails from the providers that come through get sent via punycode (even if I specifically sent it to the domain with the umlaut/non-ASCII-char). GMail on the other hand actually sends the mail to the domain that contains the umlaut (Non-punycode, even if I specifically use the punycode format in the recipient mail adress).
So, I'll either need to teach my server to handle the non-ASCII-chars or I need to teach Google to send via punycode. Or teach my server to translate umlauts to punycode. Option 2 is obviously not really on option, so 1 or 3 it is.

Log from non-GMail hoster mail:

```
postfix/amavis/smtp[2300]: 4Gn0zh0z4FzLnSJ: to=<user@domain1.tld>, orig_to=<user@domain2InPunycode.tld>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4, delays=0.1/0/0.01/3.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4Gn0zm04JHzLxc0)
```

Log from GMail mail:

```
Aug 14 15:06:44 s postfix/smtpd[2281]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:12340: Connection timed out
Aug 14 15:06:44 s postfix/smtpd[2281]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ot1-x32b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::32b]: 451 4.3.5 <user@dömain2.tld>: Recipient address rejected: Server configuration problem; from=<gmailuser@gmail.com> to=<user@dömain2.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ot1-x32b.google.com>
```